Handling Microphone permission from user in UWP
I am trying to create a dialog where user will be asked to give permission to use microphone in UWP. If user give permission than microphone access will be enabled. But I could not find any API regarding this which checks microphone permission status and any API regarding enabling microphone for a device in UWP.
The scenario is "User will be asked for permission to use Microphone. If user give access than if user changes the access runtime then an event should generate"
Any help?

When you declare Microphone capability in Package.appxmanifest, the first time you use the microphone after installing the app, UWP will automatically open a pop-up window where the user can choose to agree or deny. If the user wants to change permissions after that, they have to go to Settings > Privacy&security > Microphone to change it.
There is currently no UWP API to check the status of microphone permissions. It is recommended that you use try catch to capture the exception that the microphone cannot be accessed, and pop up a ContentDialog to remind the customer to turn on the permission in Settings > Privacy&security > Microphone.
    private async void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      
        try
        {
            MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
            settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;
            await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 

            ContentDialog noMicDialog = new ContentDialog()
            {
                Title = ex.Message,
                Content = "Please enable Microphone permission for this app in Settings",
            
                PrimaryButtonText="Go to Settings",
                CloseButtonText="Cancel"

            };

            noMicDialog.PrimaryButtonClick += NoMicDialog_PrimaryButtonClick;

            await noMicDialog.ShowAsync();
        }

       
    }

    private async void NoMicDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
        bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:privacy-microphone"));
    }

